# How to access web project from selenium based unit test project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

I have two projects in my solution Web and SeleniumTests which is Unit Test Project.

I have TestClass with following method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Demo1()
{
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver.

    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
    // not the implementation.

    // Further note that other drivers (InternetExplorerDriver,
    // ChromeDriver, etc.) will require further configuration 
    // before this example will work. See the wiki pages for the
    // individual drivers at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki
    // for further information.
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Notice navigation is slightly different than the Java version
    //This is because 'get' is a keyword in C#
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");

    // Find the text input element by its name
    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

    // Enter something to search for
    query.SendKeys("Cheese");

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
    query.Submit();

    // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
    // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until((d) => { return d.Title.ToLower().StartsWith("cheese"); });

    // Should see: "Cheese - Google Search"
    System.Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);

    //Close the browser
    driver.Quit();
}
```

All is fine but in real world i don't want to access Google.com but certain page of Web Project. Is there a way to access it without explicitly writting as url in `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");`

For example i want to access ~/Default.aspx of Web Project.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call GoToUrl() you have to pass it a valid URL. "~/Default.aspx" is not a valid HTTP URL.